# Unable to turn on wireless on new Lenovo IdeaPad laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I just bought a Lenovo IdeaPad laptop which is running Windows 7. I can connect to the Internet if I use Ethernet - however, I cannot seem to turn on the wireless.

The little notification on the bottom right says "No connections are available".  When I press the function key + (key that has wireless symbol) then *Lenovo Wireless Device Settings* comes up and says:

> First switch on wireless

I can't see any wireless button, so how can I switch on wireless as required?

Comment: Molly has a pic of the s10 and my answer has an s12. Let us know which one you have.

Comment: check this http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht072207?tabName=Solutions

Answer (score 1):

Which model is it?

I found this review about the IdeaPad S12, but not sure if it is the one you have. It is that switch right in the middle, next to the vent?

Here is the review: http://www.crunchgear.com/2009/08/06/review-lenovo-ideapad-s12-netbook-with-via-nano-cpu/

[image: int]

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is blue text under the function (F1-F12) Keys. Try pressing the Function Key + The wireless and see if that does the trick ;)

I have a dell by the way .. but it seems like a logical answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Acer Extensa 5620 after installing Windows 7.  I would press the button to turn on wi-fi but nothing happened.

The fix was to download the wi-fi driver from Acer's website.  This was the last thing I thought of doing as the device showed up OK in the device manager.

Perhaps Lenovo has an updated driver on their site.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Y550 there is a little baby switch at the left hand side corner on. Like if you have your hands on the keyboard it will be under your left arm. It is on the black very front part of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the wireless problem for windows 7 for me on the idealpad S12:

Download bios update from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds010252).

Even though it says windows XP bios update, run it from windows 7. After the update is done it will restart your laptop. When windows boot up, your wireless will be on.

**NOTE**:

1. The wireless switch on the side should be on before you do the bios update.
2. **DO NOT TURN THE SWITCH OFF** after the the update. It will disable the wireless again and you will have to run bios update again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found my Ideapad wireless switch because of this thread. And because of that let me share a photo of where yours might be located and how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Drivers for Caps lock OSD, Energy management then Wireless.

(Use the Serial number of the laptop to find specific drivers in [Lenovo Support](http://support.lenovo.com))

If WiFi still doesn't work change the boot order so that it boots from PXE (PCI LAN) before booting from Hard Drive.

This worked for me.

Found on:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_S205

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case:

Intel Wireless LAN Driver for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - ThinkPad
(https://support.lenovo.com/in/pl/downloads/ds112915)

I tried many other drivers and all of them didnt work or got me BSOD.
Remember first install drivers like chipset etc and leave that for later.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same issue of saying "No connections are available", and finally fixed it by turning a physical switch on in front side of the laptop. Cheers!